# Panasonic CF-27 How to boot from USB using CD or Floppy

Tags: boot, usb-storage

I have old Panasonic CF-27 laptop. I don't have a case for the HDD, so I can't put any HDD in there. The notebook has 1 USB port, but I can't boot from USB.

I created a USB bootable pendrive with Windows 98 startup files (using HP Format Tool).  I want to install Windows 98 (FAT), now that I have USB DOS on pendrive.

Does anyone know any way how to create a CD / Floppy startup disk that will allow me to boot from USB?

I know that it is possible, sometimes I was using  "[PLoP CD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-from-usb-without-bios-support-via-plop-cd/)", but in this case it won't work. When I select "USB" it starts "reading - blinking" from USB forever (I waited over 30 minutes).

Comment: I forget to add, i want install Windows 98   (FAT) now i have USB DOS on pendrive.

Comment: I edited your question to include that. You can always use the [edit] button to add more information to your post later.